# SyntaxError uncaught while using py_compile

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, django-rest-framework

I have defined the following function inside a class in python, where I'm trying to compile python code from external source.
The python code comes in, is written to a file and then the file is sent to the below function.
When I'm trying to call the function as:

```
self._check_code_for_errors(source_file)
```

It does not execute the except block, where I'm catching the SyntaxError exception.

```
def _check_code_for_errors(self, source_file):
    try:
        file_ = open(source_file.name, 'r')
        py_compile.compile(file_.name)
    except SyntaxError:
        return {'errors': 'You have a problem in your syntax'}
    except (OSError, IOError):
        return {'errors': 'Some error has occurred, please try again'}
```

**Update:**

```
class ValidatePythonCodeViewSet(generics.CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (PlainTextParser, )
    """
    The view set below accepts code from post request, executes it and then
    returns the appropriate results (error or output)
    """

    def _write_code_to_file(self, source):
        # file is a reserved word in python 2.x, so using file_
        with open('tempPythonCode.py', 'w') as file_:
            file_.write(source)

        return file_

    def _check_code_for_errors(self, source_file):
        try:
            file_ = open(source_file.name, 'r')
            py_compile.compile(file_.name, doraise=True)
        except py_compile.PyCompileError:
            return {'errors': 'You have a problem in your syntax'}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        source = request.data

        if not source:
            raise InformationMissingInRequestError()
        else:
            source_file = self._write_code_to_file(source)
            response = self._check_code_for_errors(source_file)

        if response.get('errors', None):
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            #execute code here and return
            pass

        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The request that I'm making is:
[image: Request]

**TraceBack**

```
  File "tempPythonCode.py", line 1
    import os\nprint 'hi
                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Internal Server Error: /api/python/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dhruuv/.virtualenvs/pythoneval/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dhruuv/.virtualenvs/pythoneval/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dhruuv/.virtualenvs/pythoneval/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dhruuv/.virtualenvs/pythoneval/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dhruuv/.virtualenvs/pythoneval/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dhruuv/.virtualenvs/pythoneval/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dhruuv/projects/PythonEval/api/views.py", line 44, in post
    if response.get('errors', None):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
[10/Feb/2016 09:45:44] "POST /api/python/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87401
```

**Update 2**

I tried it in ipdb, which worked just fine!

```
In [5]: try:
    py_compile.compile('testing.py', doraise=True)
except py_compile.PyCompileError:
    print 'dfsssssssssssss'
   ...:     
dfsssssssssssss
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SyntaxError is not a runtime error, and you cannot catch it in code. However, py_compile does not raise SyntaxError; as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html#py_compile.PyCompileError) shows, it raises `py_compile.PyCompileError`.

**Edit** So there are a couple of things wrong with your code here. Firstly, again as the documentation shows, you need to pass `doraise=True` to compile in order to get it to raise an error.

And the other exception is happening because you're not returning anything from `_check_code_for_errors` if it succeeds. You probably should return an empty dict.

Comment: I tried that earlier, by catching py_compile.PyCompileError in that function, but even that did not work.

Comment: Can you show the traceback? Perhaps you have an actual syntax error in your function.

Comment: Yes, I understand about returning the empty dict if the function succeeds.
There is more code used after that, but trimmed it to keep it succinct.
I'll try with doraise=True, and post results

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not execute the except block and returns an empty dict from _check_code_for_errors method.
Though I gave it a try in ipdb, which works!
What is still going wrong here? :(